# ember how not to render parents template?

Tags: ember.js

I have a nested routes like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path : '/'});
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new', {path: '/:post_id'});
 });
});
```

My 'posts' page shows recent posts, and my 'posts/new' page should show only a form for creating new post, so I shouldn't render template for 'posts' page in 'posts/new'. How can I do this and is it even right way?

Comment: Sidenote: `this.resource` is deprecated, you should only use `this.route` going forward. The difference is that `this.resource` does not reset the namespace, which in this case doesn't matter because `posts` is already top-level.

Comment: @lock thanks, didn't know about deprecation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your template code responsible for rendering recent posts to `posts/index` from `posts`. This way you will get only a form in `posts/new`.

If you don't have `posts/index` template generated you can run:

```
ember g route posts/index
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer to Daniel's is that if the templates aren't nested, then maybe the routes aren't nested. Here's how your router would look:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path : '/'});
  this.route('posts');
  this.route('posts.new', {path: 'posts/:post_id'});
});
```

The file path would still be `app/routes/posts/new.js`. Or the pods equivalent.